# X has 232 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 241 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to make a prediction using knn and I have following lines of code:

```
def knn(trainImages, trainLabels, testImages, testLabels):
    max = 0
    for i in range(len(trainImages)):
        if len(trainImages[i]) > max:
            max = len(trainImages[i])

    for i in range(len(trainImages)):
        aux = np.array(trainImages[i])
        aux.resize(max)
        trainImages[i] = aux

    max = 0
    for i in range(len(testImages)):
        if len(testImages[i]) > max:
            max = len(testImages[i])

    for i in range(len(testImages)):
        aux = np.array(testImages[i])
        aux.resize(max)
        testImages[i] = aux

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(list(trainImages))

    trainImages = scaler.transform(list(trainImages))
    testImages = scaler.transform(list(testImages))

    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
    classifier.fit(trainImages, trainLabels)

    pred = classifier.predict(testImages)

    print(classification_report(testLabels, pred))
```

I got the error at `testImages = scaler.transform(list(testImages))`. I understand that its a difference between arrays number. How can I solve it?

Comment: sklearn expects input as (n_samples, n_features). If your second dimension in train and test set is not equal, then not only in sklearn it is incorrect and raise error, but also in theory it does not make sense. Feature dimension of test and train set should be equal.

Comment: They are not equal. Should I resize the dimension of test with train's dimension?

Comment: No. How did you split your data? And please tell me what is your data and it's shape?

Comment: My images have different heights and widths. For example, first image is (212, 207, 3) and the second(214, 201, 3). How can I make all (224, 224, 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scaler` in scikit-learn expects input shape as `(n_samples, n_features)`.
If your second dimension in train and test set is not equal, then not only in sklearn it is incorrect and cause to raise error, but also in theory it does not make sense. `n_features` dimension of test and train set should be equal, but first dimension can be different, since it show number of samples and you can have any number of samples in train and test sets.

When you execute `scaler.transform(test)` it expects `test` have the same feature numbers as where you executed `scaler.fit(train)`. So, all your images should be in the same size.

For example, if you have 100 images, `train_images` shape should be something like `(90,224,224,3)` and `test_images` shape should be like `(10,224,224,3)` (only first dimension is different).

So, try to resize your images like this:

```
import cv2
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (224,224)) #don't include channel dimension
```

Comment: I was wondering how it fits NLP problems where some features in the training dataset could be missing in the test dataset? How does one ensure that all the important words in the training set are also present in the test set? Does not sound feasible in real-world use-cases.

Comment: @AnjaniDhrangadhariya That's another question. Words in NLP domain are treated in other ways. To make it short, there is a vocabulary, tokenizer and embeddings which help you handle this situation.