ValueError: X has 2 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input
I am having this error in my code'
ValueError: X has 2 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input.'
I was training my model for prediction of magnitude of RSC(Radar Cross Section) using Neural Networks.

Did you check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68525454/18667225 ? If this doesn't help please edit your question and share a minimal reproducible example!
